# Qt: showing text under the mouse cursor when over a QLabel object

Tags: c++, qt

I'm coding an application with a GUI using C++ Qt and I'd like to add a precise feature to my it: I have a custom class inheriting from the QLabel object in a panel and I'd like to have an information showing up in the mouse cursor when above this area, the information would be a text function of the coordinate of the cursor in this precise panel. I've been looking over for examples to implement that but I'm now even thinking that I must have a really blurry idea of the objects I'll need as my researches are not returning anything similar. Do you have an idea of how to implement it?

Thank you in advance.

Edit: pushing my researches led me to this: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtooltip.html

Apparently a QToolTip object is what I'm looking but I need to associate it with a MouseEvent that would make it appear only when the mouse is over the QLabel, looking into it ... Of course advice is still more than welcome ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not reimplement paintEvent, and use `void QPainter::drawText ( const QPoint & position, const QString & text )` method?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I may have to reimplement something as I'm not happy with the QToolTip object (it takes some delay to show up, and doesn't get actualized as you move the mouse over the QLabel).  Do you think that your solution could give me something appearing neatly over a QLabel used for drawing? (I'm testing as I'm asking this...)

Comment: @Learningisamess i think about it a while. Why not implement your own tooltip class? Something like that - ToolTip::ToolTip(const QString& text) : QLabel(0, Qt::ToolTip | Qt::BypassGraphicsProxyWidget) {setText(text)}. And then in mouseMoveEvent of your label just call tooltip->move(event->getGlobalPos()). This way you will absolutely control the tooltip.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this isn't something you already tried and didn't work. But from your answer it seems like you are looking at `QToolTip` object instead of `QWidget` which has a method called [setToolTip](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#toolTip-prop) to support a tool tip.

That said if you already have a custom class derived from `QLabel` you can intercept the mouse events and set the tool tip message. For example:

```
bool MyLabelClass::event ( QEvent* event )
{
    if( event.type() == QEvent::MouseMove )
    {
        QMouseEvent mouseEvent = dynamic_cast< QMouseEvent* >( event );

        if( mouseEvent )
        {
            QString toolTipStr( "Mouse is at x:%1, y:%2" );
            toolTipStr.arg( mouseEvent.globalX(), mouseEvent.globalY() ); 
            setToolTip( toolTipStr );
        }
    } 

    // Always return false as we aren't blocking the event.
    return false;
}
```